# How do I solve cloudy day problem using Dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was solving [cloudyday problem on hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cloudy-day/problem):

> City has many towns. `p` is an array of population of `n` towns. `x` is an array of location of towns on 1 dimensional array (thus a numeric location). `y` is an array of location of clouds. `r` is an array of extent or breadth of clouds. Population in city under cloud is said to be in dark, rest of population are said to be sunny region. i-th cloud covers every town with location in the range `[y[i]-r[i],y[i]+r[i]]`. City has a technology that can burst only single cloud. Write function to return max population that can be ensured to be in sunny region by bursting any single cloud.

Below is my attempt (with inline comments):

```
from collections import defaultdict 

def maximumPeople(p, x, y, r):
       
    loc2cloudy = defaultdict(bool) 
    
    for c in range(len(y)): # mapping location to if it is cloudy
        for r_i in range(y[c]-r[c],y[c]+r[c]+1):
            loc2cloudy[r_i] = True 
            
    # print(dict(loc2cloudy))
    
    sunny_popn_count = 0 # population not under any clound
    
    loc2popn = defaultdict(int)
    
    for t in range(len(x)): # mapping location to its population
        loc2popn[x[t]] += p[t]
        if loc2cloudy[x[t]] == False:
            sunny_popn_count += p[t] 
        
    # print(dict(loc2popn))
    
    max_cloud_popn = 0
    
    for c in range(len(y)): 
        cloud_popn = 0
        for r_i in range(y[c]-r[c],y[c]+r[c]+1): # finding population under cloud
            cloud_popn += loc2popn[r_i]     

        max_cloud_popn = max(max_cloud_popn, cloud_popn) 

    # print('{}:{}'.format(t, sunny_popn_count))
            
    return sunny_popn_count + max_cloud_popn
```

Out of 27 test cases, it passes 2, fails in 2 and rest all are runtime errors. Where did I make mistake?

Comment: You are getting the wrong answer, because you didn't consider that a town can be covered by more than one cloud, so bursting a cloud doesn't necessarily make all the towns under it sunny.  Runtime errors are probably from consuming a very large amount of memory whenever the numbers in the arrays are very large.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I corrected the code and posted as an answer. I have also compared the complexities with the solution which passes all test cases. Can you please review my understanding in the answer if am correct with it?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Matt in comments, I missed considering the fact that the same location can be occupied by multiple clouds. So, I fixed it with few tiny changes:

```
loc2cloudy = defaultdict(int) 
loc2cloudy[l] += 1 
if loc2cloudy[x[t]] == 0:
if loc2cloudy[l] == 1:
```

The whole code:

```
def maximumPeople(p, x, y, r):
       
    loc2cloudy = defaultdict(int) 
    
    # ===== mapping location to if it is cloudy ===== 
    for c in range(len(y)): # for each cloud O(#clouds)
        for l in range(y[c]-r[c],y[c]+r[c]+1): # for each 'l'ocation in cloud's range O(#cloud_locations)
            loc2cloudy[l] += 1
            
    # print(dict(loc2cloudy))
    
    sunny_popn_count = 0 # population not under any clound
    
    # ===== mapping location to its population =====
    loc2popn = defaultdict(int)
    
    for t in range(len(x)):  # for each town O(#towns)
        loc2popn[x[t]] += p[t] 
        if loc2cloudy[x[t]] == 0: # if town's location is not cloudy
            sunny_popn_count += p[t] # add town's population to sunny population count
        
    # print(dict(loc2popn))
    
    max_cloud_popn = 0
    
    # ===== finding population under cloud =====
    for c in range(len(y)): 
        cloud_popn = 0
        for l in range(y[c]-r[c],y[c]+r[c]+1): # for each 'l'ocation in cloud's range O(#cloud_locations)
            if loc2cloudy[l] == 1: # if there is this single cloud at the location
                cloud_popn += loc2popn[l]     

        max_cloud_popn = max(max_cloud_popn, cloud_popn) 

    # print('{}:{}'.format(t, sunny_popn_count))
            
    return sunny_popn_count + max_cloud_popn
```

This solution no more gives WRONG ANSWER in any test cases, just that there are still RUNTIME ERRORS. I feel the time complexity of this problem is O(#clouds * #locations).

Below is another solution with different approach:

```
def maximumPeople(towns, cloud_start, cloud_end):
    towns = sorted(towns) # sort by index-0 i.e. location
    cloud_start = sorted(cloud_start)
    cloud_end = sorted(cloud_end)

    cloud_start_j = 0
    cloud_end_k = 0
    clouds = set()
 
    d = defaultdict(int)  # cloud index : total population sunnied if burst
    free = 0
    for town_i in range(len(towns)): # O(#towns)
        town_x = towns[town_i][0]

        # find all clouds that occupy this town

        # add all clouds that start before town in clouds set

        while cloud_start_j < len(cloud_start) and cloud_start[cloud_start_j][0] <= town_x: # O(#clouds)
            clouds.add(cloud_start[cloud_start_j][1])
            cloud_start_j += 1

        # remove all clouds that end before town from clouds set

        while cloud_end_k < len(cloud_end) and cloud_end[cloud_end_k][0] < town_x: # O(#clouds)
            clouds.remove(cloud_end[cloud_end_k][1])
            cloud_end_k += 1

        if len(clouds) == 1: # if there are more than 1 cloud at location, ignore location
            # towns[town_i][2] = list(clouds)[0] # list of clouds at town location (unused)
            d[list(clouds)[0]] += towns[town_i][1] # add to population of this cloud 
        elif len(clouds) == 0: 
            free += towns[town_i][1]

    return max(d.values(), default=0) + free
```

The time complexity of this solution seem to be O(#towns * #clouds). This solution passes all test cases.

|  | Solution 1 | Solution 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Time complexity | O(#clouds * #cloud_locations) | O(#towns * #clouds) |
| Space complexity | O(#cloud_locations) for `loc2cloudy` and `loc2population` | O(#towns) for `towns`, O(#clouds) for `cloud_start`, `cloud_end`, `clouds` and `d` |

So, its really `#cloud_locations` that is causing trouble at least.

For space complexity, definitely O(#cloud_locations) > O(#cloud) as each cloud will occupy at least one location. But, I guess we cant compare O(#cloud_locations) with O(#towns).

For time complexity, we may not be able to directly compare O(#clouds * #cloud_locations) and O(#towns * #clouds), however if it happens that O(#towns) < O(#cloud_locations) in any test case, then earlier solution might end up run out of time.

Comment: test `maximumPeople([1], [0], [0], [1000000000])`, see how long it takes, and reconsider your complexity calculation.

Comment: This seems precise test case. I tried running this and ended up running it more than 1 min and also filling up 3GBs of RAM. [screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/W4nFFpQd/image.png) (sorry for crude way to check time and space). I had to kill it. So, does this confirm that my complexity analysis is indeed correct? If it was, now am guessing how can I avoid coming with such inefficient approaches? Should we first design different approaches with pen and paper, then analyze their complexities and then go with implementing better one? Is this how competitive programmer usually approach the problem?

Comment: Your fingers should just know that they should (almost) never write a loop that counts up to some arbitrary number.  In terms of complexity analysis, the  `#cloud_locations` parameter is only loosely related to anything that could be considered to be the "size of the problem".   In order to come up with a reasonable solution, you need to know how long your solution takes, and how long it *should* take.  Both of those can be stated as O(...), but `#cloud_locations` should not appear in those expressions.  It's not useful.

Comment: Let me rephrase: "#cloud_locations (locations occupied by clouds) is more arbitrary than number of towns and number of clouds and hence we should avoid writing solutions that  have time / space complexities based on this number?" Am I correct with this interpreation?

Comment: To be more precise, the worst case #cloud_locations is *exponential* in the size of the problem, so if its a factor or term in your complexity, then you are writing an exponential time algorithm...  And this problem doesn't require an exponential time algorithm.

Comment: I didnt get "worst case #cloud_locations is exponential in the size of the problem". Consider the town has L locations and c clouds. In the worst case each cloud cover all locations. So in worst case the loops will take O(c*L), right? I am unable to see if it can be O(c^L) or O(L^c). Or in other words, I am unable to see tree-like growing behavior which usually results in exponential time complexity. What I am missing here?

Comment: Look at the test case I wrote you -- it's less than 40 characters long.  That's the size of the problem.  Every zero I add to the big number makes you do 10 times as much work -- exponential.